# how to Delete unfiltered (hidden) data from excel 2010 using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this blog and request you all to help me on the below code. Currently I am trying to select the criteria (based on list of unique codes) and delete the unfiltered data which i am unable to do. Hence request the add on programme for this. Thanks

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A5:K125000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=EngID
ActiveSheet.Range("A5:K125000").Select
ActiveSheet.Rows("A5:K125000").EntireRows.Hidden.Delete
ActiveSheet.Rows.Hidden = False
```

Comment: Easier to filter for records that don't match the criteria and delete them using `Specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)` otherwise you'll have to loop.

Comment: hey rory thanks for the help could you please provide me the looping programme? i tried using this Criterial ="<> EngID" to delete other than filtered but its not taking :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's the reverse filtering method:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("A5:K125000")
    .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>" & EngID
    If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

and here's the looping method:

```
Dim rgHidden              As Range
Dim n                     As Long
ActiveSheet.Range("A5:K125000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=EngID
For n = 5 To 125000
    If Rows(n).Hidden Then
        If rgHidden Is Nothing Then
            Set rgHidden = Rows(n)
        Else
            Set rgHidden = Union(rgHidden, Rows(n))
        End If
    End If
Next n
If Not rgHidden Is Nothing Then rgHidden.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.Range("A5:K125000").AutoFilter
```

Comment: thanks a lot rory :) u r Star.................... thanks once again it worked well :)